# ASM exception thrown at

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I have a problem in compiling this assembly code. It says that I have an exception thrown at line 25. In `esi` I have the address of the matrix and I'm trying to put at a specific address the value of one.

```
_while:
        CMP ebx , 0 
        JB _end_while
        CMP edx , 0 
        JE _conditie
        MOV   [esi] , 0 
        ADD esi ,4 
        DEC edx 
        SUB ebx , 4 
        JMP _while
        _conditie:
        MOV dword ptr [esi] , 1 // here is the problem
        ADD esi , 4 
        MOV edx, 5 
        SUB ebx , 4 
        JMP _while
_end_while:
```

Comment: Did you really intend to use `JB` (unsigned <) rather than `JL` (signed <)?

Comment: surely no, as after `cmp ebx,0` the CF=0 always, so `jb` will be never triggered, so Michael probably found your problem (because then `esi`, at the moment of crash (after few correct loops), is no more *"address of matrix"*, but somewhere way beyond that into the memory the process does not own any more). You should have checked the crash report, where the `esi` is pointing, and figure out yourself it was already way past "matrix" memory.

Comment: you were totally right . Can you explain to me , why is not changing the value of the dresses , please ?

Comment: void matrice_unitate(int *, int)
{
 _asm
 {
  MOV eax, [EBP + 12]
  MOV ebx , [EBP+12]
  MUL ebx 
  MOV ebx, 4
  MUL ebx
  MOV ebx, eax
  XOR eax, eax
  SUB ebx , 4
  MOV esi, [EBP + 8]
  XOR edx, edx

  _while :
   CMP ebx, 0
   JL _end_while
   CMP edx, 0
   JE _conditie
   MOV [esi], 0
   ADD  esi, 4
   DEC edx
   SUB ebx, 4
   JMP _while
   _conditie :
   MOV [esi], 1
   ADD esi, 4
   MOV edx, 5
   SUB ebx, 4
   JMP _while
   _end_while :

 }
}

Comment: What compile do you use and compile options? Using inline assembly like this is usually very error prone, and it sounds like you are just learning assembly, so you should rather switch to assembler and pure assembly, with C inline asm it's two times more things to learn at the same time, one the assembly itself, two how to write correct C inline version which will cooperate with remaining C around. Rather learn only assembly first, then the inline rules (or even better, you will probably realize by that point that you don't want to mix it with inline C, and use it separately).